# How to implement the onmouseover effect in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want a scrollbar to show up when the `onmouseover` event is triggered on element `A`.

How is this done with actionscript 3?

Comment: What is element `A`? Is it a movieclip, button, etc. Also are you using the component scrollbar in Flash?

Answer (score 3):

for this explanation :

- instance name "spriteA"= your element 'A' is a Sprite that you have on your stage with 
  some background graphic on it.
- instance name "scrollbar" = your scrollbar is another Sprite that you will have on your stage someplace, since you didn't ask how to get the scrollbar to work, I'll assume you already have.
- both spriteA and scrollbar are children of the main document class or main stage

Code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

toggleScrollbar(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT));

spriteA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, toggleScrollbar);
spriteA.buttonMode = true;

//and if needed:
spriteA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, toggleScrollbar);

private function toggleScrollbar(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(e.type)
    {
        case "rollover":
            scrollbar.visible = true;
            break;

        case "rollout":
            scrollbar.visible = false;
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Sprite` here?

Answer (score 0):

```
A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showScrollbar);
A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideScrollbar);

function showScrollbar(e:MouseEvent):void
{
//make the scrollbar visible
}

function hideScrollbar(e:MouseEvent):void
{
//hide the scrollbar again
}
```

Comment: How can i add the effects to show scrollbars like fade out, wipe out etc.. ?